# Comments are not being saved to database - Unable to autoload constant CommentController

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm building a forum app in RoR, and I cant save comments on the database at the moment.

when the 'create comment' button is pressed the following error appears on the terminal:

> LoadError (Unable to autoload constant CommentController, expected
>   /..//app/controllers/comment_controller.rb to define it)

here are my routes:

```
devise_for :users
root                              to: 'post#index'

#Posts
get    '/posts/new',             to: 'post#new' 
get    '/post/:id',              to: 'post#show',      as: 'show'
get    '/post/:id/edit',         to: 'post#edit',      as: 'edit'
post   '/post',                  to: 'post#create'
put    '/post/:id',              to: 'post#update',    as: 'update'
delete '/post/:id',              to: 'post#destroy',   as: 'delete' 

#Comments
post  '/post/:post_id',  to: 'comment#create', as: 'new_comments'
```

the comment_controller.rb:

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_comment, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  before_action :authenticate_user! 

  def index
    @comments = Comment.all
  end

  def new
    @comment = Comment.new
  end

  def create 
    @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
    @comment = @post.comments.new(comment_params)
    @comment.user = current_user
    @comment.assign_attributes(comment_params)


      if @comment.save
        format.html { redirect_to @link, notice: 'Comment was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render json: @comment, status: :created, location: @comment }
      else
        format.html { render action: "new" }
        format.json { render json: @comment.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end


  end

  def destroy
    @comment.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to :back, notice: 'Comment was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_comment
      @comment = Comment.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def comment_params
      params.require(:comment).permit(:post_id, :content, :title, :user_id)
    end


end
```

the html form:

```
<div id="comments-form">
 <%= form_for @comment, url: new_comments_path(@post), method: :post, remote: true do |f| %>
    <%= f.label :title %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :title, placeholder: "Type the comment title here" %><br>
    <%= f.label :content %><br>
    <%= f.text_area :content, placeholder: "Type the comment content here" %><br>
  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

and the post and comment models.

post:

```
class Post < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :user
    has_many :comments
    validates :title, :content, presence: true
end
```

comment:

```
class Comment < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :user
    belongs_to :post
    has_many :reviews
end
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: found the error, just changed class CommentsController < ApplicationController to class CommentController < ApplicationController

Comment: You might want to follow Rails conventions and use plural controller names (`posts_controller` and `comments_controller`). Furthermore, I suggest using the [`resources`](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#crud-verbs-and-actions) instead of writing all routes manually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just found the error, i was defining the controllers class incorrectly.

it should read class `CommentController < ApplicationController` and not class

```
CommentsController < ApplicationController
```

Answer (score 0):

Always use resources like

```
resources :comments
```

So the url will automatically generate and if you want to do nested url under post, you can do this like

```
resources :posts do
   resources :comments
end
```

And for your correction your controller name is correct like "Comments" as rails convention, you need to specify here like this:

```
#Comments
post  '/post/:post_id',  to: **'comments#create**', as: 'new_comments'
```